# roslaunch: using ampersand (&) in gscam config

Tags: roslaunch, gscam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I am trying to use an ampersand (&) in my launch file for gscam but it's apparently bad syntax. Here's the output:

```
 Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 7, column 92
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="cam_name" value="my_camera" />

  <!-- Start the GSCAM node -->
  <env name="GSCAM_CONFIG" 
      value="souphttpsrc location=http://10.16.63.224/control/faststream.jpg?stream=full&fps=0 timeout=5 ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace" />
  <node pkg="gscam" type="gscam" name="$(arg cam_name)">
    <param name="camera_name" value="$(arg cam_name)" />
    <remap from="camera/image_raw" to="$(arg cam_name)/image_raw" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

If I remove the "&fps=0" from the end of location, then the launch file works, but I need it there to operate my camera properly. Is there a way to use "&" in a launchfile? maybe a delimiter?

Thanks,
-Frank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214266/roslaunch:-using-ampersand-(&)-in-gscam-config/) by [frankb](https://answers.ros.org/users/22516/frankb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. I googled the issue under general XML syntax, not just a roslaunch problem.

You can use "& amp;" for the "&". So my code now becomes this and it works!

```
<launch>
  <arg name="cam_name" value="my_camera" />

  <!-- Start the GSCAM node -->
  <env name="GSCAM_CONFIG" 
      value="souphttpsrc location=http://10.16.63.224/control/faststream.jpg?stream=full&amp;fps=0 timeout=5 ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace" />
  <node pkg="gscam" type="gscam" name="$(arg cam_name)">
    <param name="camera_name" value="$(arg cam_name)" />
    <remap from="camera/image_raw" to="$(arg cam_name)/image_raw" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [frankb](https://answers.ros.org/users/22516/frankb/) with karma: 101 on 2015-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1